# Sidon sets in finite groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

> Suppose $G$ is a group, $S \subset G$. Let’s call $S$ a Sidon subset iff $\forall$ quadruples $(a, b, c, d)$ of distinct elements of $S$ we have $ab \neq cd$ (named after Simon Sidon who studied such subsets in $C_\infty$). Let’s define $Sid(G)$ as the maximal possible cardinality of a Sidon subset in $G$. Do there exist such $0<c<C<+\infty$, such that $c \leq \frac{Sid(G)}{\sqrt{|G|}} \leq C$ for any finite group $G$?

The existence of $C$ can be proved the following way:

If $S$ is a Sidon subset of $G$, then $|G| \geq |S^2| \geq \frac{|S|(|S| - 1)}{2}$, thus $C = \sqrt{2} + 1$ will work.

The only thing I know about $c$ is that Erdos proved such constant exist for finite cyclic groups $G$. But does it exist for all finite $G$?

[This question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438898/sidon-sets-in-finite-groups)

Comment: Did you try $S_n$?

Comment: The paper of Babai and Sos "Sidon Sets in Groups and Induced Subgraphs of Cayley Graphs" (European J. Comb. (1985) 6, pp.101-114) is highly relevant.

Comment: @Seva:  This paper does not  answer the question. Right?

Comment: @MarkSapir: seems it does not.

Comment: Sets which meet the upper bound with equality are called planar difference sets, and are closely related to finite projective planes. I am not aware of work which addresses your question, but this might give you some additional terms to search for.

Comment: @Seva: Apparently there is a gap. The constant lower bound is known for $Sid(G)/\sqrt[3]{|G|}$ and the constant upper bound is known for $Sid(G)/\sqrt{|G|}$,

Comment: @PadraigÓCatháin: This is for Abelian groups only?

Comment: Not necessarily, though the character theory works out much more nicely when the group is abelian, so difference sets have been studied more intensively in that case.